# Memory card/tile cgame

Tags: python

Currently working on a memory card game in python. Where theres a board of cards with words.

Two cards contain the same word and you try to collect pairs of cards with the same word.

> For example if there is 10 cards on the board there is 5 words. You get pairs by flipping the two cards with the same word in a row. If you get it wrong both cards flips back. The game reminds a bit of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohnOgkb_W5U) game but my version uses words instead.

My current code is a mess but I'm only a beginner. I'am currently stuck and don't know how to continue. Would appreciate if someone could help me out a bit.

```
class Playingboard:
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points

    def randomCard(self):
        for row in range(1, 5);:
            for column in range(1, 5):
                print (i*j, end " ")
            print()



class Cards:

    def __init__(self, ShowCard = False, word):
        #
        self.ShowCard = ShowCard
        self.word = word

    def ShowCard(self):
        #Shows the word

    def __lt__ (self):
        #Compares the cards to see if it's the same word

wordlist =[car, computer, house, speaker, piano, drums]
cardlist = []  
amount_word = 6


for i in amount_word:
    card = Card(wordlist[i])
    cardlist.append(card)
    cardlist.append(card)
```

Comment: where are you stuck? what do you want to do?

Comment: I have tried figuring out ShowCard but. Not sure how to define it.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to run your code. When Python throws an error, go fix that part of you program so that it doesn’t cause an error. Then, repeat that process until the whole thing runs without any errors.

There are many errors in your code as you have posted it. Below is a copy of your code that will run without any errors. I suggest that you compare it to your version so that you can see where you are making mistakes.

```
class Playingboard:
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points

    def randomCard(self):
        for row in range(1, 5):
            for column in range(1, 5):
                print (i*j, end = " ")
            print()

class Cards:
    def __init__(self, word, ShowCard = False):
        #
        self.ShowCard = ShowCard
        self.word = word

    def ShowCard(self):
        pass
        #Shows the word

    def __lt__ (self):
        pass
        #Compares the cards to see if it's the same word

wordlist =['car', 'computer', 'house', 'speaker', 'piano', 'drums']
cardlist = []  

for word in wordlist :
    card = Cards(word)
    cardlist.append(card)
    cardlist.append(card)
```